# How can get custom tags inside web component

Tags: web-component, stenciljs

I'm new in webcomponents with stenciljs, I'm testing creating a select, the idea with this code create and render the select:

```html
<rhx-select label-text="A select web component">
      <rhx-select-item value="1" text="option 1"/>
      <rhx-select-item value="2" text="option 2"/>
</rhx-select>
```

The problem i have is how can i get the tags that inside my web component?

this is my code:

```js
import { Component, h, Prop, } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'rhx-select',
  styleUrl: 'select.css',
  shadow: true,
})

export class RhxSelect {
    @Prop() labelText: string = 'select-rhx';

    @Prop() id: string;
    
    @Element() el: HTMLElement;

    renderOptions() {
        let data = Array.from(this.el.querySelectorAll('rhx-select-item'));
        return data.map((e) =>{
            <option value={e.attributes.getNamedItem('value').value}>{e.attributes.getNamedItem('text').value}</option>
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                
                <label htmlFor={this.id}>
                    {this.labelText}
                </label>

                <select id={this.id} class="rhx-select">
                  {this.renderOptions()}
                </select>

            </div>
        )
    }   
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Simply add your webcomponents bundle like this `<script src="path/to/bundle.js" defer></script>`. This makes sure the DOM is parsed before the components are initialized.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786436/accessing-childnodes-of-custom-elments/49799296#49799296

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `@Element()` decorator you can parse the children with vanilla JS:

```
getItems() {
  return Array.from(this.el.querySelectorAll('rhx-select-item'));
}
```

You can then use those elements and their properties/attributes however you want, for example to generate a list of `<option>` elements.

A good example is [`ion-select`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/64719f49f979c0296a01827d3c02599a48ba93a6/core/src/utils/watch-options.ts#L1) which gets the children in the `childOpts()` getter function.

A couple things to keep in mind:

1. You'll probably want to hide the items with `display: none`
2. If the options might change after the initial load you'll need to listen for those changes. Ionic uses the [`watchForOptions` function](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/64719f49f979c0296a01827d3c02599a48ba93a6/core/src/utils/watch-options.ts#L1).

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thanks for you answer. i just add the function to render the options but nothing happaned. 

you can see the code and html render links below:

[gist](https://gist.github.com/aguileraq/f55ce541cfd50734d85b8bd546d80a67)
[render pic](https://ibb.co/xqmGpLn)

Comment: Looks like the items are nested. Try non-self-closing tags (`</rhx-select-item>`)

Answer (score 0):

`this.el.querySelectorAll` won't return any elements until after the component has rendered once, so that its children are available in the DOM. Therefore you will have to use something like the `componentDidLoad` hook:

```js
export class RhxSelect {
  // ...

  @State()
  items: HTMLRhxSelectItemElement[] = [];

  componentDidLoad() {
    this.items = Array.from(this.el.querySelectorAll('rhx-select-item'));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={this.id}>
            {this.labelText}
        </label>

        <select id={this.id} class="rhx-select">
          {this.items.map(item => (
            <option value={item.getAttribute('value')}>{item.getAttribute('text')}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Note however that `componentDidLoad` is only executed once, after the component has loaded. If you want your component to support dynamic changes to the options, then you'll have to use something else, like `componentDidRender`, but then you'll also have to make sure you don't end up with an infinite render loop. There's also a couple ways to solve this, by combining different lifecycle methods.

See https://stenciljs.com/docs/component-lifecycle for a list of all available lifecycle methods.